# Unable to load shared library while running the program

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am facing strange issue while loading shared library in a cpp program. When the make file is executed then it works fine -

```
LIB_RELEASE = $(LIB)-lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lmmcheng_github -lgomp
```

But when I run this using the output file which is generated as a result of this make file, it gives me error as -

```
./bin/mmcheng_densecut: error while loading shared libraries: libmmcheng_github.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**PS** I have placed the libmmcheng_github.so in the folder /usr/local/lib

Error Screenshot - [image: See during makefile all works fine however later it fails]

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your dynamic loader (ld.so in Linux ) is not able to find the shared library you need.

Comment: Yeah that I can also see in the error but what should I do to resolve this. I used to have this file in my current folder however due to this error i moved it to the /usr/local/lib folder

Comment: Can you run the "ldd" command against your executable? It may give some clues...

Comment: Hey Greycon, I got the resolution by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my .bashrc file, however I am not very excited with that solution

Comment: Ok cool. Did you try putting your .so into /usr/lib (as opposed to /usr/local/lib) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment string, read [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

Although this is [discouraged practice](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html) but at least it will help you make one step forward...

also, read [this question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime)

Comment: Cool..This worked, but there got to be a better way to do this I think...however temporarily I have placed the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my .bashrc file